# Trying to copy a LSTM model - it's not working

Tags: python, lstm

I'm trying to copy a LSTM model that I found from here:
[Stock Market-Predict volume with LSTM model](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ehsandahesh/stock-market-predict-volume-with-lstm-model/notebook)

I'm getting stuck on the last line of code. Specifically, this is what it tells me:

[image: screenshot of code]

I literally know next to nothing about code just basic python.

If you want to, I can add you to like the google drive collaboratory so you could look at the whole code.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

The arrays aren't the same size, which is required for the pyplot.plot function to work. So just cut less items out of the data array like so from:

```
plt.plot(data.index[-640:], test_y, color='blue',label='Actual')
plt.plot(data.index[-640:], yPredict, alpha=0.7, color='red',label='Predict')
```

to

```
plt.plot(data.index[-300:], test_y[-300:], color='blue',label='Actual')
plt.plot(data.index[-300:], yPredict[-300:], alpha=0.7, color='red',label='Predict')
```

just to explain this even more what its saying is that the size of the arrays aren't the same, so what I did was cut out the items equally + less because it said that test_y had 372 items, however I don't know if this is the same for yPredict, it could be even smaller. good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is their anyway i can keep all the data in there? It would be good if i could just see the whole time span

Comment: You could set the size of the cut to the size of the available data, thats all I can think of.

Comment: @Sebastion Bilek, im not sure what this means. Im new to copding

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answer, the train and test sets are built here:

```
num = int(data_reframed.shape[0]*0.8)
value = data_reframed.values
train = value[:num, :]
test = value[num:, :]

train_x, train_y = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
test_x, test_y = test[:, :-1], test[:, -1]
```

While yPredict is calculated here:

```
yPredict = Model.predict(test_x)
```

Hence, the shape of `yPredict` and `test_y` has to be the same, and that has to be `(data_reframed.shape[0] - num,)`, since `num` is the size of the training set. Then, due to `series_to_supervised?,` data`has one row more than`data_reframed`. So, you can write:

```
plt.plot(data.index[num+1:], test_y, color='blue',label='Actual')
plt.plot(data.index[num+1:], yPredict, alpha=0.7, color='red',label='Predict')
```

And plot everything.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasnt worked. Im still pretty confused. I can share you the actual link to my code if you want.

Comment: @Bancks yes sure!

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vk_JlIoGY6K9fUHsGMVo_NA-nZYbGmsA?usp=sharing

Comment: @Bancks I see, it's probably because you are using `series_to_supervised` which adds lagged observations and removes one row (drops the `NaN` at the start). Try `data.index[num+1:]` instead of `data.index[num:]`. However, did you check the `series_to_supervised` function you are using? It seems that it returns `var(t+1)` instead of `var(t-1)` is that what you want?